# get id of child element when parent is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors, jquery

Hello I have seen similar posts but none answer what I want to accomplish
I made a sample here
http://jsfiddle.net/edgardo400/R6rVJ/

What i basically want is when a click happens in the parent you get the id of the child
and store it in a variable so i can pass the variable currentID to the code below  otherwise I will have to replicate this code 9 times for each id from box1 to box9

```
 jQuery(currentID).delegate("a", "hover", function(event){

        var $img = jQuery(this).parent("li").find('img');
        var image = jQuery(this).attr('data-img');
         jQuery('.defaultimg').stop(true, true).fadeOut();
        if( event.type === 'mouseenter' ) {

            if($img.length){
                $img.show();

            }else{
                jQuery(this).parent("li").append('<img id="theImg" src="' + image + '" />');
            }

        }else{
            if($img){
              $img.hide();  
            }
             jQuery('.defaultimg').stop(true, true).fadeIn();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: If the click event occurs outside the bounds of the child(ren) element(s), how should this system decide *which* child id to show?

Comment: Did you know that you only have to write `jQuery` in its long form once? By wrapping your code in `(function($) { .... })(jQuery);`, you can use `$` no matter if `noConflict` has been used or not.

Comment: Sorry if not clear the system will know because it is the children that is clicked I just want the system to tell me the id of what child was clicked and from there do the events based on that id
i have a working model here well when I say the id anyways
http://testdomain.edgardoroldanonline.com/apple-power/
you can see it working in poison control

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$('#boxes').on('click', function(e) {
    var currentID = e.target.id;
    console.log(currentID);

......rest of code
```

Comment: i tried it before and it gave me the id of the parent... whatI want is that when the child is clicked for jquery to get its id and then use it to perform the fadeouts and everything using that id

Comment: Well, then you tried it wrong :-)  Seems to work for me, it gives the ID of the box clicked [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/R6rVJ/1/), as for the rest of the code, I just can't guess what it's supposed to look like as it's missing in your fiddle.

Comment: I looked at your fiddle and I see the console.log is still there but I cant see the id it does not show up in firebug. Im new to fiddle how do you see it? and what id do you get do you get boxes or the childs id box1 for example

Comment: Anything logged to the console strangely enough shows up in the console. However, there is an error in the rest of the script that makes Firebug hang, works in Chrome though. Try a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/R6rVJ/2/) without the other faulty code, and it shows up.

Comment: ok saw it and it works amazing :D and with only 3 lines of code do you know how to make it work with a class as well

Comment: Sure, if you need to change the jQuery selector just change the hash to period (# -> .), if you need to change `e.target.id`, do `e.target.className`

Comment: do you know if `e.target` is supported across devices and browsers? does it work on mobile too?

Answer (score 2):

In javascript it would be:

```
var a = document.getElementById('#boxes');
a.onclick = function(e){
    console.log(e.target.id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only wish to make your code working and displaying on your console the box name, you should probably set

```
jQuery('#boxes').bind('click', function(event) {

     var currentID = jQuery(event.srcElement).attr('id');

     /* rest of your code */
});
```

You might want to do something easier

```
jQuery('#boxes').children().bind('click', function() {

   jQuery(this).delegate... 

});
```

Although I'm not sure why you are doing this ...

fixed http://jsfiddle.net/nxTDA/

Comment: I really apprecieate to show why i am doing this you can see it in 
http://testdomain.edgardoroldanonline.com/apple-power/   when you click in poison control the box appears and I want that when you hover in any of the ul items a different image appears

http://jsfiddle.net/edgardo400/cham5/  new version

so far the only way it has worked is to place the id box1).delegate

Comment: I was just curious, because every problem has many solutions and someone would propose a better solution if he can see the problem from bigger perspective. Fair enough.

Comment: its ok :D so what do you think is it possible to get jquery store the id of the child when its clicked